# MS ACCESS Subselect "At most one record can be returned by this subquery."

Tags: select, microsoft-access

Alguém saberia me dizer o pq desse subselect estar causando o erro: "At most one record can be returned by this subquery."?

```
(SELECT TOP 1 J.observacao " +
 " FROM tblPendenciaHistorico J " +
" INNER JOIN tblPendenciaPendenciaHistorico JH " +
   " ON J.historicoId = JH.pendenciaHistoricoId " +
" WHERE JH.pendenciaId = P.pendenciaId " +
" ORDER BY J.data DESC) AS historicoStatus"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrigi adicionando a PK no order by.

```
(SELECT TOP 1 J.observacao " +
 " FROM tblPendenciaHistorico J " +
" INNER JOIN tblPendenciaPendenciaHistorico JH " +
   " ON J.historicoId = JH.pendenciaHistoricoId " +
" WHERE JH.pendenciaId = P.pendenciaId " +
" ORDER BY J.data DESC, J.historicoId DESC) AS historicoStatus"
```